# how to view the download queue for a Kindle

Tags: kindle, amazon, ebook-management, hardware, download

How can I purge, edit, or, at least, view, the download queue for a device?

Probably I just have too many pending downloads and a slow connection.  But, perhaps the Kindle is stalled.  I was seeing a "downloading" note in the top left, but, not at present -- and yet there are books which should be queued for download.

It's possible to [view pending deliveries through the web interface](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122397/24327).

Answer (score 2):

*[Note: I know this thread is old, but I found it via a web search and have an answer for people in the future who find it that way as well.]*

There does not appear to be a built-in app, menu item, or button that allows you to view the download queue. On my Kindle Fire HDX, however, I can swipe down from the top, and any in-progress downloads are shown in the notification/message area. Tapping one of those takes me to the download queue page.

To reset stalled downloads, you can try the following:

- cancel the download, via the swipe-down area or the download page, then restart it
- power the device on and off
- restart the "Appstore" app from Settings > Applications